# shown image only after mouse hover 2 times?

Tags: jquery, html, onmouseover

It's very simple code

```
 <img src="images/Card.png" id=I1 class="img"/> 
 <img src="images/Card.png" id=I2 class="img"/> 
 <img src="images/Card.png" id=I3 class="img"/> 
 <img src="images/Card.png" id=I4 class="img"/> 

 <img src="images/Capture1.JPG" id="myImage1" style="display: none ; " />
 <img src="images/Capture2.JPG" id="myImage2" style="display: none ; " />
 <img src="images/Capture3.JPG" id="myImage3" style="display: none ; " />
 <img src="images/Capture4.JPG" id="myImage4" style="display: none ; " />

<script>
 $('.img').mouseover(function() {

        var GetId = this.id.substring(1);

        $("#I" + GetId).hover(
        function () { $("#myImage" + GetId ).show();  },
        function () { $("#myImage" + GetId ).hide();  }  ); 

    });
</script>
```

It's working fine, but it have one problem you need put mouse over 2 times to display image.

Google the problem but no solution.

Can any one help?

Thank you

Comment: `$().hover()` is an binding event listeners, just like your mouseover is binding an event listener.  So of course it takes two times.  Also, this logic is going to bind the hover event listener every time the image is mouseover, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your logic, and fix your issue in the process, by using a data field on the mouseover images.

```js
$('.img')
  .on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).show();
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/Card.png" id=I1 class="img" data-target="myImage1" />
<img src="images/Card.png" id=I2 class="img" data-target="myImage2" />
<img src="images/Card.png" id=I3 class="img" data-target="myImage3" />
<img src="images/Card.png" id=I4 class="img" data-target="myImage4" />

<img src="images/Capture1.JPG" id="myImage1" style="display: none ; " alt="image1" />
<img src="images/Capture2.JPG" id="myImage2" style="display: none ; " alt="image2" />
<img src="images/Capture3.JPG" id="myImage3" style="display: none ; " alt="image3" />
<img src="images/Capture4.JPG" id="myImage4" style="display: none ; " alt="image4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you can group the images together should do this by using pure css. If not use Taplar's answer.
Example:

html:

```
<!-- repeat for all your images -->
    <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="img">
    <img class="image-on-hover">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-on-hover{
display:none
}

.img:hover ~.image-on-hover{
display: block
}
```

Explanation:
The :hover Selector on CSS will be triggered when an element is hovered. With the ~ selector you can select a child element on the same level (you could call it "neighbour-element"). Since we don't want to display all neighbouring hover-images, we wrap the pairs of image and hover-images together

Different option if your grouping is exactly like the example:

```
.image-on-hover{
display: none;
}

/*repeat for every image pair */

#I1:hover ~ #myImage1{
display:block
}
```

Comment: This only works if they are grouped together, no?  The OP is not grouping what is being hovered with what is being shown on hover.

Comment: Yes, i don't know the entire use case. It really depends on how these containers are actually grouped. It can also work if the structure is different though. Would have to see the actual html

Comment: e.g. if the grouping is exactly like the example you can do this:

`.hover-image{ display: none};
#I1: hover ~ #myImage1{ display: block}`

and so on

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't  group the images together. But  Taplar's  code it what I am looking for. but thank you for another options.